# [fltuter]sharedpreference real time update is not working

Tags: flutter

new to flutter, tying to make simple timer app.

when the user entered to textField and click the "save" button in IndividualSetting class, the text is saved in sharedpreference.
and then, cakeNameSetting class loads what I saved in sharedpreference and displays it.

IndividualSetting class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


class IndividualSetting extends StatefulWidget {

  final int value;

  const IndividualSetting({Key? key, required this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<IndividualSetting> createState() => _IndividualSettingState();
}

class _IndividualSettingState extends State<IndividualSetting> {

  final _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    _textEditingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  Widget dialogContent(BuildContext context, String title, String content, int value) {
    late SharedPreferences _prefs;

    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(                                            //설정 제목
            title,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 18.0,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),                          //여백
          TextField(controller: _textEditingController),   //텍스트 입력창
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),                          //여백
          ElevatedButton(                                  //텍스트 저장 버튼
            onPressed: () async {
              _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
              await _prefs.setString('cakename-$value', _textEditingController.text);
            },
            child: Text('save'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),                            //여백
          Text("debugging"),
          ElevatedButton(                                   //창 닫기 버튼
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(); // Close the dialog
            },
            child: Text('OK'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Dialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          child: dialogContent(context, '설정', 'content', widget.value),
        );
      }
  }
```

cakeNameSetting class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class cakeNameSetting extends StatefulWidget {

  final int value;

  const cakeNameSetting({Key? key, required this.value}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<cakeNameSetting> createState() => _cakeNameSettingState();
}

class _cakeNameSettingState extends State<cakeNameSetting> {

  String? cakeName = 'hello';


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadCakeName();
  }

  Future<void> _loadCakeName() async {
    final SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      cakeName = _prefs.getString('cakename-${widget.value}');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (cakeName != null)
      ? Text(cakeName!)
      : Text('Error');
  }
}
```

I want to update the "cakename" value in real-time when I loaded string data from sharedpreference in this code:

```
cakeName = _prefs.getString('cakename-${widget.value}');
```

Unfortunately,  It doesn`t change in real-time. It is changed only when I restarted this app.

I think that It will work because I used setState method when I update the "cakeName" value. But It doesn`t work.

What should I do with situation?